# systematic or random errors or systemic errors or random errors?

Tags: conjunctions

Hello I have always had this confusion. Could you please explain me, which one of these is correct and why?

> The difference 0.038 grams is due to systematic or random errors.

or

> The difference of 0.038 grams is due to systematic errors or random errors.

Intuitively, I feel like the first one is correct, but I am not sure.

Comment: I seem to be [in the minority](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=systematic+errors%2Csystemic+errors&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) on this one, but ***systematic errors*** sounds really "odd" to me (it suggests *[deliberate] **methodically planned*** errors). I'd always expect ***systemic errors*** (unwanted errors that arise purely because of ***the nature of the particular system*** used to carry out procedures or gather information).

Comment: ...cf [***systematic racism*** vs ***systemic racism***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=systematic+racism%2Csystemic+racism&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Comment: I don't understand the spelling errors in questions as the computer should point them out; Systemic errors are errors from a system. Systematic errors are one made over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions convey the intended meaning quite effectively. I don't think there is any significant difference here.

In your preferred version (which I would prefer less), 0.038 grams stands in apposition to the noun phrase *The difference*; In other words, it simply adds further detail to the subject of the sentence (*The difference*).

In the second version, instead of the appositional placement of 0.038 grams you're connecting it with *The difference* with the preposition *of.* The entire noun phrase *The difference of 0.038 grams* then functions as the subject of the sentence.

I would further prefer *either* in the second version and write:

> The difference of 0.038 grams is due to either systemic (thank you @FumbleFingers) errors or random errors.

On a separate note, it is not okay to say *Could you please explain me.* You explain a point, a nuance, or some such thing— not a person.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated it.

Comment: "it is not okay to say Could you please explain me" — so just to add on, the correct way of phrasing this is "Could you please explain it to me"